# HTML + CSS only - three equal columns (33%~) with equal heights

Tags: html, css

I'm having a huge issue and I suppose it may be not "doable", but I thought it would do no harm to ask.

I need three equal columns, with equal heights, but I don't know their heights, so this must be dynamic.

To make it even harder, each of these columns has different background colour.

Ideally the content would be vertically aligned, but that's not necessary.

Comment: how are they going to be dynamic? is content gonna be added with javascript? In that case you need to check the height of the element with the most height and put the min-height for all the elements to that height.
Otherwise you could try and look for a flexbox solution. Please be more specific tho.

Comment: You should be able to do this with flex pretty easily, otherwise you're going to need javascript

Comment: @mnemosdev dynamic means I don't know the content yet, thus I don't know the height of container. The content won't change once loaded.

Comment: Actually, I take it back.  https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/yqrhw 100% css solution after a quick google.

Comment: @Alex any way you could provide an example with use of flex?

Comment: I'm having a huge issue with your question, I can't see what you have tried... :P

Comment: @Joum I have tried plenty of solutions, randomly tweaking CSS to get the result, but none worked (I either get columns of different heights or they don't go full-width / equal-width). In short, I tried using display: table and table-cell.

Comment: I bet you did, and still, none of them shows up in your question. If you need help, you should at least let people know what you have tried.

Comment: @user1970395 This is not the place to make a contest. Please put the REAL PROBLEM you are facing.

Comment: @RayC I don't understand you really, I put the real problem I'm facing, I'm facing a design where I need three equally distributed columns of equal height based on the height of the "longest" one (its content). Perhaps the question is not specific enough, but since I've already received my answer, I see no problem anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syden's answer is close, but has issues with maintainability (changing the margin or padding of almost anything will break it).

Here is an alternative which addresses those issues and will work for any number of columns.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.item {
  flex: 1;
  /* These can be changed or removed without affecting the layout / scrollbars */
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
}

.item-blue { background: blue; }
.item-green { background: green; }
.item-red { background: red; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item-blue">
  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
  </div>
  <div class="item item-green">
  Text Text 
  </div>
  <div class="item item-red">
  Text Text Text Text Text Text 
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this with flexbox maybe:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.column {
  width: 33%;
  height: 100%;
  background: lightgray;
  /*margin: 5px;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Could you perhaps tell me how to remove the spacing between divs?

Comment: I did resize the viewport and it seems to scale well (columns remind equal width & height, no collapsing occured), what browser did you use? I checked with chrome.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty easy using css tables. It never breaks, since it is always kept in a row, and it also allows to vertically align the content.

```css
.cols {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.cols > div {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 33%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.cols > div:nth-child(1) { background: blue; }
.cols > div:nth-child(2) { background: red; }
.cols > div:nth-child(3) { background: green; }
```

```html
<div class='cols'>
  <div>
    Test testTest testTest testTest test
  </div>
  <div>
    Test<br />Test<br />Test<br />Test<br />Test<br />Test<br />Test<br />Test
  </div>
  <div>
     Test
  </div>
</div>
```